# jgit addFilePattern not working for my absolute path to a file

Tags: java, git, jgit

jgit version 4.6.0 ,
java 1.8 ,
windows 10

I have written a java program to push to a git repository where as I want to push specific files at a time instead of pushing all files.

`git.add.addFilePattern(".").call();`  works fine.
but

`git.add.addFilePattern("D:\\myGitRepo\\files\\file1.txt").call();` is not working.

"myGitRepo" folder contains the .git folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

The Javadoc of method [`AddCommand#addFilepattern(String)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/v4.6.0.201612231935-r/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.java#L109-L111) says that: parameter `filepattern` is repository-relative path of file/directory to add (with `/` as separator). So you cannot use absolute path and cannot use backslash `\`. Indeed, you should:

- Use repository-relative path
- Use slash `/` to delimit directories on all platforms, even on Windows

### Detail

When executing `call()` in [`AddCommand`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/v4.6.0.201612231935-r/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.java), JGit calls [`PathFilterGroup`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/v4.6.0.201612231935-r/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/filter/PathFilterGroup.java) to create the file patterns, which calls [`PathFilter`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/v4.6.0.201612231935-r/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/filter/PathFilter.java) behind the screen. From `PathFilter`, we can see a more detailed definition about the file pattern:

```
/**
 * Create a new tree filter for a user supplied path.
 * <p>
 * Path strings are relative to the root of the repository. If the user's
 * input should be assumed relative to a subdirectory of the repository the
 * caller must prepend the subdirectory's path prior to creating the filter.
 * <p>
 * Path strings use '/' to delimit directories on all platforms.
 *
 * @param path
 *            the path to filter on. Must not be the empty string. All
 *            trailing '/' characters will be trimmed before string's length
 *            is checked or is used as part of the constructed filter.
 * @return a new filter for the requested path.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             the path supplied was the empty string.
 */
public static PathFilter create(String path) { ... }
```